# Using Shopware "Add to shopping cart" button in plugin

Tags: php, plugins, smarty, smarty3, shopware

I'm writing a custom plugin for Shopware 5.
How do I display the "Add to shopping cart" button on a page for an arbitrary article?

Currently I'm fetching some existing articles directly from the database. I then assign these articles to a custom frontend tpl file (which extends a default tpl file). Now I want the button to be displayed for one of these fetched articles.

I found the smarty block that holds the button (`frontend_detail_buy_button` in `themes/Frontend/Bare/frontend/detail/buy.tpl`), but I don't know how to extend/change it to my needs.

My Shopware version is 5.2.8.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, I right understand your question, but in case you need to add `add to cart` button you need to transfer full `sAddToBasket` form.

```
<form name="sAddToBasket" method="post" action="{url controller=checkout action=addArticle}" class="buybox--form" data-add-article="true" data-showOverlay="false" data-eventName="submit"{if $theme.offcanvasCart} data-showModal="false" data-addArticleUrl="{url controller=checkout action=ajaxAddArticleCart}"{/if}>
{if $sArticle.sConfigurator&&$sArticle.sConfiguratorSettings.type==3}
    {foreach $sArticle.sConfigurator as $group}
        <input type="hidden" name="group[{$group.groupID}]" value="{$group.selected_value}"/>
    {/foreach}
{/if}

<input type="hidden" name="sActionIdentifier" value="{$sUniqueRand}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="sAddAccessories" id="sAddAccessories" value=""/>

<input type="hidden" name="sAdd" value="{$sArticle.ordernumber}"/>

{$sCountConfigurator=$sArticle.sConfigurator|@count}

{if (!isset($sArticle.active) || $sArticle.active)}
    {if $sArticle.isAvailable}
        <div class="buybox--button-container block-group{if $NotifyHideBasket && $sArticle.notification && $sArticle.instock <= 0} is--hidden{/if}">

            <div class="buybox--quantity block">
                {$maxQuantity=$sArticle.maxpurchase+1}
                {if $sArticle.laststock && $sArticle.instock < $sArticle.maxpurchase}
                    {$maxQuantity=$sArticle.instock+1}
                {/if}

                <select name="sQuantity" class="quantity--select">
                    {section name="i" start=$sArticle.minpurchase loop=$maxQuantity step=$sArticle.purchasesteps}
                        <option value="{$smarty.section.i.index}">{$smarty.section.i.index}{if $sArticle.packunit} {$sArticle.packunit}{/if}</option>
                    {/section}
                </select>
            </div>

            {* "Buy now" button *}
            {if $sArticle.sConfigurator && !$activeConfiguratorSelection}
                <button class="buybox--button block btn is--disabled is--icon-right is--large" disabled="disabled" aria-disabled="true" name="{s name="DetailBuyActionAdd"}{/s}"{if $buy_box_display} style="{$buy_box_display}"{/if}>
                    {s name="DetailBuyActionAdd"}In den Warenkorb{/s} <i class="icon--arrow-right"></i>
                </button>
            {else}
                <button class="buybox--button block btn is--primary is--icon-right is--center is--large" name="{s name="DetailBuyActionAdd"}{/s}"{if $buy_box_display} style="{$buy_box_display}"{/if}>
                    {s name="DetailBuyActionAdd"}In den Warenkorb{/s} <i class="icon--arrow-right"></i>
                </button>
            {/if}
        </div>
    {/if}
{/if} 
</form>
```

You can [see](http://joxi.ru/Y2LY93zC9LROaA) how it work on real site [there](http://allyouneedfresh.cn.com/).

Depends of your needs you can use `sAddAccessories` and `sAddAccessoriesQuantity` inputs for add the list of products to basket, [example](http://joxi.ru/krDlB6zsEZRW9r) you can see [there](http://shopware5.instance.in.ua/mountain-air-adventure/fashion/women/123/speed-hoody-fz?number=SW10123).
In case you can show your site I can provide to you more suitable solution for your case. Don't forget about configurator and variations when you will apply custom add to cart button.

I hope you deems this answer helpful.

Comment: I tired to copy the relevant HTML for the form and putting a value for `sAdd` (an order number for some article) but when I click the button I get an error: `503 (Service Unavailable)` for `http://[DOMAIN]/checkout/ajaxAddArticleCart?callback=jQuery21406407849721801058_1488057735447&sActionIdentifier=&sAddAccessories=&sAdd=[ORDERNUMBER]&__csrf_token=[TOKEN]&isXHR=1&_=[NUMBER]`.

Comment: Open 
/engine/Shopware/Controllers/Frontend/Checkout.php 
and find:
function ajaxAddArticleCartAction
On first line of function add line:
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Then you will see error text and can understand problem, because I can't answer based on request..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand it right, but you can look on the detail page how shopware add an article to the basket. Than change sBasket with s article. shopware use severals parameters.

For extending use:

```
{extends file="parent:frontend/detail/index.tpl"}
```

With `{$smarty.block.parent}` inside a block, will fill the Block on your Plugin template with there Default content.

P.d.: Sorry for my english